# What is distance of ship from coastline(AB) if it is 167° and 205° from A and B respectively?

Tags: trigonometry

Two points A and B on a straight coastline are 1km apart, B being due east of A. If a ship is observed on bearings 167° and 205° from A and B respectively, what is its distance from the coastline?

Any tips?

I ended up with at triangle containing the degrees 142°, 13° and 25° and then using the sin rule to find sides BC and AC. But it already feels like I'm going in the wrong direction since I'd have to get the perpendicular of C which would make two triangles and then use pythagoras AND simultaenous equations. Seems wrong.

Comment: How would you get $205^\circ$ as a measurement in the first place? What is the reference point?

Comment: That is the question in the textbook. The reference point is B, I assume

Comment: @DonThousand:  bearings are taken relative to due North, so the ship is mostly South and a little East of A, mostly South and a little more West of B.

Comment: Sketch the situation out.  From A, a bearing of $167$ is $167-77$ degrees south of east; from B, a bearing of $205$ is $270-205 = 65$ degrees south of west.  You are therefore looking at $\triangle ABC$, with $\overline{AB}$ east-west, and $C$ south of them both; the triangle has angles $77$, $65$, and what?  You can now proceed with the law of sines, or else use the more analytical geometry approach of Karn's answer.

Comment: From your comments I just realised I didn't know the meaning of 'bearings'. Now it's clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your triangle approach certainly could work (save for any careless mistake).

Personally, I would just define $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(1,0)$ and define two lines
\begin{align}
x&=y\tan(167^\circ)\\
x-1&=y\tan(205^\circ)
\end{align}

and find the intersection via
\begin{align}
y\tan(205^\circ)+1&=y\tan(167^\circ)\\
y(\tan(205^\circ)-\tan(167^\circ))&=-1\\
y&=\frac{-1}{\tan(205^\circ)-\tan(167^\circ)}
\end{align}

You can see the graph to help you see better.

[image]

Comment: I pasted in your graphic so people don't have to click through.  Roll back if you want

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Law of Sines to find another side.  Then you can find the area of the triangle from two sides and the included angle (i.e. $\frac{1}{2}a b \sin C$).  Finally, you can solve for the distance to shoreline because it is the altitude to the base of 1km.